# For what values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is the matrix $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ is the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\  x_1 & x_2 & x_3 &x_4 \\   x_1^2& x_2^2 & x_3^2 & x_4^2\\   x_1^3& x_2^3 & x_3^3 &x_4^3  \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible

Do I need to calculate det 2x2, 3x3 and so on or?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: The matrix is invertible if and only if the $x_i$ are pairwise different.